# proving that there is a function $x_0$ such that $||x-x_0||_2 <\epsilon$ with $x_0(0)=x_0(1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $\mathcal C([0,1])$ be the set of all functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$, $x\in \mathcal C([0,1])$ and $\epsilon>0$. Prove that, there is a function $x_0\in\mathcal C([0,1])$ with $x_0(0)=x_0(1)$ such that $$||x-x_0||_2 <\epsilon$$

Using the Stone-Weierstrass theorem I was able to prove that there is a function $x_0$ with the desired properties such that, for any $\beta > 0$ $$||x-x_0|| <\beta$$

Where $$||f||=\sup_{x\in[0,1]} |f(x)|$$

I'm having some trouble now proving that $||x-x_0|| <\beta\implies ||x-x_0||_2 <\epsilon$.

Is this possible or is this the wrong approach to the problem?

Comment: There must be some flaw in your application of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem because in general it is not possible to approximate any continuous function by those that satisfy $x(0)=x(1)$

Comment: The set $A =\{f\in\mathcal C([0,1]) : f(0) = f(1)\}$ is a sub-algebra that separates points, so this means that $\bar A = \mathcal C([0,1])$, right? @BrunoKrams

Comment: It does not seperate points by its very definition

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães How would you separate $0$ and $1$ in this set?

Comment: omfg, I forgot about 0 and 1, you are right xD @GBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$x_n(t)=\begin{cases} x(t) & {1\over n}\le t\le 1\\ (1-nt)x(1)+ nt\,x({1\over n}) & 0\le t\le {1\over n}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $x_n$ is continuous and $x_n(0)=x_n(1)=x(1).$ Moreover $\|x_n-x\|_2\to 0.$ Indeed $$\|x_n-x\|_2^2=\int\limits_0^{1\over n}|x_n(t)-x(t)|^2\,dt\le {1\over n} 4\|x\|^2
\underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\beta =\epsilon$
then $||x-x_0||=\sup _{t\in[0,1]}|x(t) - x_0(t)| <  \epsilon \implies$

$$|x(t)-x_0(t)| < \epsilon,\ \ \ \forall t $$
$$\implies|x(t)-x_0(t)|^2 <\epsilon^2$$

$$\implies\int_0^1 |x(t)-x_0(t)|^2 dt < \epsilon^2$$
$$\implies||x-x_0||_2^2  < \epsilon^2$$
$$\implies ||x-x_0||_2 < \epsilon$$